# Creating random positions of triangles using Webgl

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I've just started to learn webgl  I've been trying to generate triangles with random size and positions just like in this picture using javascript.

[image: Random triangles]

I know that I need to use a for loop inside the function initScene() but I am not sure how to put the new positions into the array. Please help.

```js
// Application info.
var app = app || {};
var nbTriangles=20;
function getContextGL(canvasElement)
{
    var can = document.getElementById(canvasElement);
    if(can == null)
    {
        return [null, null];
    }

    var gl = can.getContext("webgl");

    return [can, gl];
}


function createShaderFromElement(gl, id) 
{
    // Grab the script element.
    var scriptElt = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!scriptElt) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Retrieve the source.
    var scriptSource = scriptElt.textContent;

    // Identify shader type based on element type.
    var shaderObj;
    if (scriptElt.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") 
    {
        shaderObj = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } 
    else if (scriptElt.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") 
    {
        shaderObj = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } 
    else 
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Compile and check status.
    gl.shaderSource(shaderObj, scriptSource);
    gl.compileShader(shaderObj);

  var ok = gl.getShaderParameter(shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);

    if (!ok)
    {
        var msgError = gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj);
    alert(msgError);
        gl.deleteShader(shader);

        return null;
    }

    return shaderObj;
}

function buildProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader)
{
    if (!vertexShader || !fragmentShader)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var progObject = gl.createProgram();
  if(!progObject)
  {
    alert("Can't create program object.");
    return ;
  }

  gl.attachShader(progObject, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(progObject, fragmentShader);

  gl.linkProgram(progObject);

    var ok = gl.getProgramParameter(progObject, gl.LINK_STATUS);
  if(!ok)
  {
    var msgError = gl.getProgramInfoLog(progObject);
    alert(msgError);

    gl.deleteProgram(progObject);
    return null;
  }

    return progObject;
}

function initGL()
{
    app.gl.viewport(0,0,app.can.width, app.can.height);


    app.gl.clearColor(0.,0.,0., 1.0);
    app.gl.clear(app.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    var vs = createShaderFromElement(app.gl, "vs");
    var fs = createShaderFromElement(app.gl, "fs");
    app.progObject = buildProgram(app.gl, vs, fs);

    app.gl.useProgram(app.progObject);
}

function initScene()
{
    var gl = app.gl;

    // Creer le buffer de geometrie (vertex)
    //
    
       /* Drawing one triangle:
    

        var positions = [
            // coordonnees normalisees.
            0.0, 0.1, 0.1, -0.1,-0.1, -0.1
            
        
        ];*/

        for (var i=0; i<nbTriangles;++i)
        {
        
        
        var  orig = [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0];
        var scale = Math.random() * 0.2;
        var Trans = [Math.random() * 1.6, Math.random * 1.6];
        P0 = orig[0] * scale + Trans[0];
        P1 = orig[1] * scale + Trans[1];
        P2 = orig[2] * scale + Trans[2];


        var positions= new Positions (P0,P1,P2)

        TRIANGLES.push(newPositions); 
        }


    // Creer un nouveau buffer vide.
    var posBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    // Ref sur l'attribut "pos" dans le vertex shader.
    var posLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(app.progObject, "pos");

    // Activer le buffer. Toute operation sur buffer
    // sera appliquer a posBuffer (il est actif!).
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, posBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(posLocation);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(posLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false /*no normalization*/, 0 /*stride*/, 0 /*offset*/);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

}

function render()
{
    var gl = app.gl;

    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    
        // Dessiner le buffer.
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3* nbTriangles);
}

function init()
{
    [app.can, app.gl] = getContextGL('can');
    if (app.can == null || app.gl == null)
    {
        alert("Can't init canvas or context");
        return;
    }

    app.can.width = app.can.height * (app.can.clientWidth / app.can.clientHeight);
    
    var rect = app.can.getBoundingClientRect();
  app.scaleX = app.can.width / rect.width;
  app.scaleY = app.can.height / rect.height; 

    initGL();
    initScene();
    render();
}
```

```css
div 
{
}

#main-div
{
display:inline-block;
}

#viewport, #manager
{
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
}

.color
{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}

.blue{
    background:#0f0;
}

#viewport
{
    width: 600px;
    height:700px;
}

#can
{
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    border:1px solid orange;
}

#manager
{
    width: 200px;
    height:300px;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;

}

#obj-list
{
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Colored Quad</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="colored_quad.js"></script> 

    <script id="vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  precision mediump float;
    attribute vec2 pos;

  void main() 
    {
        vec4 pt = vec4(pos, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl_Position = pt;
  }
 </script>

    <script id="fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  precision mediump float;
  void main() 
    {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
  }
  </script>

</head>

<body onload="init();">

    <div id="main-div">

            <div id="viewport">
                <canvas id="can" >Your browser doesn't seem to support canvas!</canvas>
            </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might find [these articles](https://webglfundamentals.org) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code I get an error "positions is undefined"

Maybe you should try to fix those errors before posting your question? If you're just learning JavaScript maybe [these lessons would help](https://eloquentjavascript.net/)

In any case, this code

```
// Creer le buffer de geometrie (vertex)
//

   /* Drawing one triangle:


    var positions = [
        // coordonnees normalisees.
        0.0, 0.1, 0.1, -0.1,-0.1, -0.1
        
    
    ];*/

    for (var i=0; i<nbTriangles;++i)
    {
    
    
    var  orig = [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0];
    var scale = Math.random() * 0.2;
    var Trans = [Math.random() * 1.6, Math.random * 1.6];
    P0 = orig[0] * scale + Trans[0];
    P1 = orig[1] * scale + Trans[1];
    P2 = orig[2] * scale + Trans[2];


    var positions= new Positions (P0,P1,P2)

    TRIANGLES.push(newPositions); 
    }
```

has a lot of basic javascript issues.

`Positions` is not defined (the first error when running it). Just looking at the code I can also see a reference to `TRIANGLES` that is not defined, `newPositions` that is not defined. Also I see `P0`, `P1`, and `P2` I'm assuming were supposed to be points but they are referencing only a single value in `orig` each instead of 2 values (x and y).  And `P2` is referencing `Trans[2]` which doesn't exist.

Here is one fix

```
      var positions = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < nbTriangles; ++i) {

        var orig = [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0];
        var scale = Math.random() * 0.2;
        var Trans = [Math.random() * 1.6, Math.random() * 1.6];
        var P0 = [
           orig[0] * scale + Trans[0],
           orig[1] * scale + Trans[1],
        ];
        var P1 = [
          orig[2] * scale + Trans[0],
          orig[3] * scale + Trans[1],
        ];
        var P2 = [
          orig[4] * scale + Trans[0],
          orig[5] * scale + Trans[1],
        ];
        positions.push(...P0, ...P1, ...P2);
      }
```

Another fix would be to loop over the points in `orig`

```
      for (var i = 0; i < nbTriangles; ++i) {

        var orig = [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0];
        var scale = Math.random() * 0.2;
        var Trans = [Math.random() * 1.6, Math.random() * 1.6];
        for (var j = 0; j < orig.length; j += 2) {
          positions.push(
            orig[j    ] * scale + Trans[0],
            orig[j + 1] * scale + Trans[1],
          );
        }
      }
```

another would be to write functions to scale and add vectors

```
      const addV = (v1, v2) => v1.map((v1Elem, i) => v1Elem + v2[i]);
      const scaleV = (v, scale) => v.map((elem) => elem * scale);

      for (var i = 0; i < nbTriangles; ++i) {

        var orig = [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0];
        var scale = Math.random() * 0.2;
        var Trans = [Math.random() * 1.6, Math.random() * 1.6];
        for (var j = 0; j < orig.length; j += 2) {
          // pull out 2 values from orig
          let p = orig.slice(j, j + 2);
          p = scaleV(p, scale);
          p = addV(p, Trans); 
          positions.push(...p);
        }
      }
```

As for adding a different color to each triangle I'd suggest you go read some [other articles on WebGL](https://webglfundamentals.org)

```js
// Application info.
var app = app || {};
var nbTriangles = 20;

function getContextGL(canvasElement) {
  var can = document.getElementById(canvasElement);
  if (can == null) {
    return [null, null];
  }

  var gl = can.getContext("webgl");

  return [can, gl];
}


function createShaderFromElement(gl, id) {
  // Grab the script element.
  var scriptElt = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!scriptElt) {
    return null;
  }

  // Retrieve the source.
  var scriptSource = scriptElt.textContent;

  // Identify shader type based on element type.
  var shaderObj;
  if (scriptElt.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
    shaderObj = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  } else if (scriptElt.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
    shaderObj = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  } else {
    return null;
  }

  // Compile and check status.
  gl.shaderSource(shaderObj, scriptSource);
  gl.compileShader(shaderObj);

  var ok = gl.getShaderParameter(shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);

  if (!ok) {
    var msgError = gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj);
    alert(msgError);
    gl.deleteShader(shader);

    return null;
  }

  return shaderObj;
}

function buildProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
  if (!vertexShader || !fragmentShader) {
    return null;
  }

  var progObject = gl.createProgram();
  if (!progObject) {
    alert("Can't create program object.");
    return;
  }

  gl.attachShader(progObject, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(progObject, fragmentShader);

  gl.linkProgram(progObject);

  var ok = gl.getProgramParameter(progObject, gl.LINK_STATUS);
  if (!ok) {
    var msgError = gl.getProgramInfoLog(progObject);
    alert(msgError);

    gl.deleteProgram(progObject);
    return null;
  }

  return progObject;
}

function initGL() {
  app.gl.viewport(0, 0, app.can.width, app.can.height);


  app.gl.clearColor(0., 0., 0., 1.0);
  app.gl.clear(app.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  var vs = createShaderFromElement(app.gl, "vs");
  var fs = createShaderFromElement(app.gl, "fs");
  app.progObject = buildProgram(app.gl, vs, fs);

  app.gl.useProgram(app.progObject);
}

function initScene() {
  var gl = app.gl;

  // Creer le buffer de geometrie (vertex)
  //

  var positions = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < nbTriangles; ++i) {


    var orig = [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0];
    var scale = Math.random() * 0.2;
    var Trans = [Math.random() * 1.6, Math.random() * 1.6];
    var P0 = [
       orig[0] * scale + Trans[0],
       orig[1] * scale + Trans[1],
    ];
    var P1 = [
      orig[2] * scale + Trans[0],
      orig[3] * scale + Trans[1],
    ];
    var P2 = [
      orig[4] * scale + Trans[0],
      orig[5] * scale + Trans[1],
    ];
    positions.push(...P0, ...P1, ...P2);
  }


  // Creer un nouveau buffer vide.
  var posBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  // Ref sur l'attribut "pos" dans le vertex shader.
  var posLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(app.progObject, "pos");

  // Activer le buffer. Toute operation sur buffer
  // sera appliquer a posBuffer (il est actif!).
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, posBuffer);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(posLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(posLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false /*no normalization*/ , 0 /*stride*/ , 0 /*offset*/ );
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

}

function render() {
  var gl = app.gl;

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)


  // Dessiner le buffer.
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3 * nbTriangles);
}

function init() {
  [app.can, app.gl] = getContextGL('can');
  if (app.can == null || app.gl == null) {
    alert("Can't init canvas or context");
    return;
  }

  app.can.width = app.can.height * (app.can.clientWidth / app.can.clientHeight);

  var rect = app.can.getBoundingClientRect();
  app.scaleX = app.can.width / rect.width;
  app.scaleY = app.can.height / rect.height;

  initGL();
  initScene();
  render();
}

init();
```

```css
#main-div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#viewport,
#manager {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
}

.color {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.blue {
  background: #0f0;
}

#viewport {
  width: 600px;
  height: 700px;
}

#can {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

#manager {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}

#obj-list {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="main-div">

      <div id="viewport">
        <canvas id="can" >Your browser doesn't seem to support canvas!</canvas>
      </div>

  </div>
  <script id="vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  precision mediump float;
  attribute vec2 pos;

  void main() 
  {
    vec4 pt = vec4(pos, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_Position = pt;
  }
 </script>

  <script id="fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  precision mediump float;
  void main() 
  {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Ty so much. Yes, I've just started to learn javascript and webgl and your answer has been an enormous help. Thank you